# Spring Security LDAP "bind must be completed on the connection"

Tags: php, spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I need to create a SpringBoot service and provide an authentication service using LDAP.
I followed this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/) and it works fine for me using an embedded local ldap server (as suggested into the tutorial)

Now I tried to use the official company LDAP server but I got this error:

```
Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A5C, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v4563];
```

This error seems related to a LDAP bind request that it's necessary. But how can I add this into the Spring Security LDAP?

This is the code where I tried to integrate the company LDAP connection:

```
@Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("userPrincipalName={0},ou=users")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=users")
        .contextSource()
          .url("ldap://companyhost:389/dc=aa,dc=company,dc=com")
          .and()
        .passwordCompare()
          .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
          .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
  }
```

I tried also with my PHP example (using the official company active directory and this works fine)

```
// connect to ldap server
    $ad = ldap_connect("ldap://".LDAP_HOST, LDAP_PORT)
        or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (ldap_bind($ad, "$user"."@".LDAP_HOST, $password)) {

  // User authenticated
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Directory Server you are connecting to does not allow 'anonymous' access, i.e. your application first has to authenticate beforehand (via and LDAP BIND operation) before performing queries. [LdapContextSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/LdapContextSource.html)

Furthermore Using password comparision ('passwordCompare()') is not LDAP best practice (I don't know why this is still in the Spring docs), itstead an LDAP BIND operation should be used to authenticate users. This lets the server compare the password as only the server knows which password storage scheme was used on the server side when the password was saved.

Using 'userDnPattern' is also not LDAP best practices as this means you have to know the Directory Information Tree (DIT) of the LDAP Directory Server. Instead let the Directory Server determine the Distinguished Name (DN) by performa search leveraging 'userSearchBase', 'userSearchFilter' [LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.html)